# Response.Write removes parenthesis ')'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I working with angular JSONP.

I generate the reponse on the server:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("{0}({1})", HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["callback"], json));
```

which writes the string:

```
angular.callbacks._b({"Currency":"USD","Balance":1000,"Bonus":100,"openPositions":[]})
```

in chrome devtool i inspect the response and it is as follows:

```
angular.callbacks._b({"Currency":"USD","Balance":1000,"Bonus":100,"openPositions":[]}
```

pay attention to the missing closing parathesis at the end of the response.

what's really wierd is that it works with objects with one property:
the object is serialize as json:

```
 new { token: "somestring"}

angular.callbacks._a({"token":"somestring"})
```

Answer (score 2):

Flush the output - HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(). It seems that your output is not being sent completely to the client due to some reasons.

Comment: flush does sends all the output but causes some other issues.
i dont know what happen but after trying your solution and then undoing it the parenthesis now appear in resposne (without using flush). thanks anyway!

Comment: what i can put which can help is already in the post. I cant upload more since this is not my private code. i really appreciate the effort!

Comment: From what you put in the post it is not clear how and when the server processing code ends.

It is definitely the "not flushed output buffer issue" and it does occur pretty randomly. It highly depends on the output content length, environment settings and all the other stuff, because the server and client interact with each other using data chunks, not complete data.

I would suggest checking that you end your response gracefully. 

I also wonder what "other issues" can the "Flush" operation cause. This is probably also correlated with some errors in the code.

Comment: my apologizes for the delay, i wasnt at work yesterday. All I do after is System.Web.Http.Ok() to return ok response. i getting an exepction about the headers cannot be set. without the ok the $http goes to error function